# google script how to move cursor to another cell in google spreadsheet same sheet by time trigger

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers

I'm a beginner. My function does good work when it is trigger by menu of script run command.
But when a time trigger the function fired it don't work.

The script with more tests to move the cursor:

I have more day's to search the same problem but not fount.
Many thanks for help!

```
    function mypos() {
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Zo");
    var cell = sheet.setActiveSelection("G11"); //getRange("G11");
    cell.activate();
    SpreadsheetApp.flush();
    var sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Za'); 
    var cs = sh.getActiveCell().getRow();
    sh.getRange(cs+1, 9).activate();
    SpreadsheetApp.flush();
    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets()[6];
    //var range = sheet.getRange('B15');
    var range = sheet.getRange(14, 7);
    range.activate();
    SpreadsheetApp.flush();
    }
```

Comment: Time-based triggers do not act on the instance of the document you are accessing. A script called from a menu, however, knows exactly which document instance it should act on. I think if you were to place `console.log("function mypos ran")` into your function and then view the Stackdriver logs for your script after your script should have run, that you will see several mentions of the script successfully running.

Comment: Rubén, thanks for you reply!

Comment: The Time-base triggers is not really necessary, which is what I'm trying to do to put an expiration time in a cell.
If the onedit (e) function has detected a correct range, the function mypos is started and in cell S2 a cell address is set where the cursor must remain.
Is there a possibility to start the function mypos if cell S2 is not empty?
This means that the function mypos does not have to be started by a Time-base trigger but only if cell S2 is not empty.

Comment: `onEdit` will only be activated when the user alters a value on the sheet. Once it has stopped running (i.e. the cursor was set someplace), there is nothing to prevent the user from moving the cursor again, to wherever they want. The only way to force a function to run repeatedly is via time-based trigger, and as you have discovered, that does not mean the function runs in the same UI instance the user is accessing.